# duplication of firebase-auth module and firebase-common-auth using own authentication server

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play-services

I'm using Google, Facebook and custom server authentication methods,
I was using Twillio messaging API for phone number verification.

Now I want to use Firebase sms verification, but I am unable to use ***com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.*** dependency for calling method **PhoneAuthProvider**
Can anyone help me to guide on it?

Using firebase-auth dependency shows this duplication error during build:

**Gradle:**

```
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential found in modules jetified-firebase-auth- 
19.3.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1) and jetified-firebase-auth-common- 
9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.EmailAuthCredential found in modules jetified-firebase-auth-19.3.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider found in modules jetified-firebase-auth-19.3.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthCredential found in modules jetified-firebase-auth-19.3.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider found in modules jetified-firebase-auth-19.3.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthProvider found in modules jetified-firebase-auth-19.3.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.GithubAuthCredential found in modules jetified-firebase-auth-19.3.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider found in modules jetified-firebase-auth-19.3.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthCredential found in modules jetified-firebase-auth-19.3.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider found in modules jetified-firebase-auth-19.3.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.TwitterAuthCredential found in modules jetified-firebase-auth-19.3.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider found in modules jetified-firebase-auth-19.3.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.UserInfo found in modules jetified-firebase-auth-19.3.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.UserProfileChangeRequest found in modules jetified-firebase-auth-19.3.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.UserProfileChangeRequest$Builder found in modules jetified-firebase-auth-19.3.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.zza found in modules jetified-firebase-auth-19.3.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1) 
Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors
```

**gradle.build(project)** dependencies are

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

**gradle.build(app-level)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
    buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.orderdoo.customer"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false;
        disable 'deprecation'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        jumboMode true
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    allprojects {

        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }


        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            mavenLocal()
            jcenter()
            google()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
            maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com" }
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }

        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
            exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        }

    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.3.0') {
        exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
    }
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.bartoszlipinski:recyclerviewheader2:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:0.2.0'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.reinaldoarrosi:maskededittext:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'
    implementation 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.hedgehog.ratingbar:app:1.1.2'
    implementation 'uk.co.ribot:easyadapter:1.5.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.rahimlis:badgedtablayout:v1.2'
    implementation 'com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.gmail.samehadar:iosdialog:1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'


    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1' //this generates duplication

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.github.ar-android:DrawRouteMaps:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'in.srain.cube:ultra-ptr:1.0.11'

    implementation 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'

    implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.1.0'

    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }


    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try execute this command as it is useful to run the build in the terminal with the following command:

```
./gradlew --info assembleDebug
```

as this will help you to figure out the complete list of all dependencies which are getting involved in conflicts:

Dependency Resolution Help: Displaying all currently known paths to any version of the dependency: Artifact(groupId=com.google.firebase, artifactId=firebase-iid)

```
-- task/module dep -> firebase-analytics@17.2.0
---- firebase-analytics:17.2.0 library depends -> play-services-measurement-api@17.2.0
------ play-services-measurement-api:17.2.0 library depends -> firebase-iid@19.0.0

-- task/module dep -> firebase-core@17.2.0
---- firebase-core:17.2.0 library depends -> firebase-analytics@17.2.0
------ firebase-analytics:17.2.0 library depends -> play-services-measurement-api@17.2.0
-------- play-services-measurement-api:17.2.0 library depends -> firebase-iid@19.0.0

-- task/module dep -> play-services-measurement-api@17.2.0
---- play-services-measurement-api:17.2.0 library depends -> firebase-iid@19.0.0

-- task/module dep -> firebase-iid@19.0.0

-- task/module dep -> firebase-messaging@17.1.0
---- firebase-messaging:17.1.0 library depends -> firebase-iid@[16.2.0]

-- task/module dep -> com.pressenger:sdk@4.8.0
---- com.pressenger:sdk:4.8.0 library depends -> firebase-messaging@17.1.0
------ firebase-messaging:17.1.0 library depends -> firebase-iid@[16.2.0]
```

From this list you  will get to know 2 things:

Where is the conflicting dependency and What versions of the conflicting dependency are.

In this case the conflicting dependency is firebase-iid: It's either @19.0.0 or @16.2.0

To fix this you must define the top-level dependency of the wrong firebase-iid explicitly in your `build.gradle`.

So in the above logs you can see that there are 2 examples of an out-dated version of firebase-iid@16.2.0. One comes from -- task/module dep -> firebase-messaging@17.1.0 the other one from a third-party library. We don't have control on the third-party library, so nothing to do here.

But for the other dependency, we have to declare it explicitly with the correct version which will force to use this one:

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'

So might be you can get an idea using this command that what is the main root cause of your problem.